# ejs is not loading css file

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

As the title says my layout.ejs file is not loading the style.css file. I have doomscrolled now for hours without finding the answer for this. I tried so many things and checked all the spellings a 100 times. When inspecting the network tab the path seems to be correct for the css file, but it gives a 404 error for it. The files are in root/public/style/style.css and root/views/layout.ejs

layout.ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
```

main.js

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    router = express.Router(),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    layouts = require("express-ejs-layouts"),
    errorController = require("./controllers/errorController"),
    homeController = require("./controllers/homeController"),
    path = require('path');   


//setting the port and the view engine as .ejs files
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3001);
app.set("view engine", "ejs"); 


router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
router.use(layouts);

router.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended: false
        })
    );
router.use(express.json());
  
// using the homecontroller
router.use(homeController.logRequestPaths);
app.get("/", homeController.index);

// Using the error controller
app.use(errorController.ResourceNotFound404);
app.use(errorController.internalError500);

app.use("/", router);

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${app.get("port")}`)
});
```

Send help!

Tried different versions of the path in the layout.ejs file and different code snippets for requiring the static file in express.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change:

```js
router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

to

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I've tried this also.